# How to unit test a method that makes an HTTP request?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am developing with the Twitter's API and I make several calls POST, GET, PUT, etc. Here an example of how I do that :

```
public function get(string $screenName): TwitterResponse
{
    try {
        $response = $this->client->getClient()->get(UserEnum::URI_GET, [
            'query' => ['screen_name' => $screenName]
        ]);
    } catch (ClientException $e) {
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());

        $response = $e->getResponse();
    }

    return new TwitterResponse($response);
}
```

I would like to know how to unit test that simple method ? I'm not sure if it's really useful to test my method because the "main" job is doing by Twitter. But I would like to reach 80% code coverage at least.

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Obviously, you don't need making the HTTP call in the tests so better mock the client